# Demoiselle no OpenJDK

Tags: java, demoiselle

Ouvi dizer que o Demoiselle não funciona com OpenJDK.

É verdade? Mesmo para o OpenJDK 7?

Há planos ou trabalho em andamento para que o Demoiselle possa ser usado com o OpenJDK, pelo menos da versão 7 em diante?

Obs: a partir do Java 7, o OpenJDK é a implementação de referência e não há "pedaços não implementados" no OpenJDK ou classes `com.sun` nas classes padrão. Portanto, utilizar o OpenJDK 7 não deveria ter problemas.

Answer (score 5):

Isso não é verdade, pois o Demoiselle funciona com o OpenJDK, inclusive na comunidade recomendamos desenvolver a partir do OpenJDK e depois testar com o JDK da Oracle.

Para verificar isso, você pode baixar o [Live DVD](http://sourceforge.net/projects/demoiselle/files/infra/demoiselle-live.iso/download) que disponibilizamos para os usuários. É uma distribuição do LUbuntu e vem somente com o OpenJDK instalado.

O que ocorre é que o Demoiselle ainda está na especificação 6 do JEE, assim algumas funcionalidades previstas no JEE7 que já é contemplado pelo OpenJDK 7 não são compatíveis.

Há um componente de certificado digital ICP Brasil que foi feito com base no JDK da Oracle porque foi desenvolvido internamente pelo SERPRO e não através do processo da Comunidade, mas [já foi corrigido](https://demoiselle.atlassian.net/browse/CER-1) para não ter essa dependência e em breve será lançada a nova versão deste componente.

Já estamos trabalhando numa nova versão do Demoiselle compatível com o JEE7.

Comment: > em breve será lançada a nova versão deste componente.

Legal, estaremos aguardando!